# MarkLogic ErrorLog Not Populated After Editing

Tags: logging, marklogic

I have a rotation of ErrorLog.txt to ErrorLog5.txt which is rotated daily.  On a particular day, an ErrorLog may get particularly big so I thought to myself what if I shrank the file in the afternoon so that is is easier to navigate?

I ran the following command to shrink it

```
sed -i -e '1,10000d' /var/opt/MarkLogic/Logs/ErrorLog.txt
```

After shrinking a couple of times, I got it to be about 4800 lines which looked pretty manageable.  The only problem is after doing this nothing else is being added to the ErrorLog.txt, it is staying the same size.  So how do I get writing again to the ErrorLog.txt?  I don't want to wait until midnight to see if things fix themselves.

Going into the admin console and clicking on the Logs tabs, I see the following listed:

```
8000_AccessLog.txt
   8000_AccessLog_1.txt

8001_AccessLog.txt
   8001_AccessLog_1.txt

8002_AccessLog.txt
   8002_AccessLog_1.txt

8041_AccessLog.txt
   8041_AccessLog_1.txt
   8041_AccessLog_2.txt
   8041_AccessLog_4.txt

8050_AccessLog.txt
   8050_AccessLog_1.txt

8051_AccessLog.txt
   8051_AccessLog_1.txt

8060_AccessLog.txt
   8060_AccessLog_1.txt
```

There is no listing for ErrorLog.txt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I did 2 things:

1. I noticed that root was the new owner of ErrorLog.txt, so I thought that might be problematic.  I changed that to daemon.
2. I then restarted from the admin console.  I didn't realize I have that power at first, but I do.  After restarting, the ErrorLogs suddenly showed up in the Logs tab.

Answer (score 0):

The files in the Data directory, including ErrorLog.txt are managed by ML server and should not be edited without expecting unexpected behaviour.

The active log files (ErrorLog.txt, AccessLog.txt or in v9 also port_ErrorLog.txt, port_AccessLog.txt) may be held open by the server.  The affect of editing open files is OS dependant and genrally 'not a good idea'.

If you stop the server you can generally safely rename or move the current ErrorLog.txt file.   You can also safely edit or move any of the rotated log files (ending in _n.txt where n=1,2,3 ...)

The best way to limit the logfile size is to adjust the rotation interval and the loglevel so as to not produce more logs then you want.   If needed, by stopping the server and moving the file out of the way.

Note: this behaviour is similar to most programs use of log files and logfile rotation.